# How to update SQL Query when a new column is added

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I was wondering if anyone could help answer this question. I currently have an SQL Query that's being displayed into a table using PHP. I use a separate PHP file to upload data to mySQL table and when I update my table with a new column I have to rerun the SQL Query to get it to update into the PHP table. I was wondering if there was a way using PHP to automatically run that SQL Query when there has been an update to the table.

Comment: New column or new row added?

Comment: I'm adding columns as it's adding times from races to a new column for the event.

Comment: When you run a query to update the table are you sending that data to a PHP script by redirecting the user to that new script and then back again? The question is a bit confusing, is it possible to add some code so we can get a better understanding of whats going on?

Comment: You shouldn't be adding columns to a races table `(racer, event_1_time, event_2_time, event_3_time... etc.)` you should have a table with columns such as `(racer, event_num, time)` where each event is distinguished by values in one event column. As far as the update, you are probably going to have to call ajax every N seconds to re-run the query and, if there is new data, that new data will display.

Comment: What I currently have is the different groups for the driver (which they compete in). I have Driver Name, Vehicle, Total Time for columns, but add a new column after every race for each driver which will then add to their total time. If there is a better way  to do what I am currently doing, please, I am all ears.

Comment: Altering a table's structure will hopefully be a fairly rare event, so there's little merit in automating the corresponding query. So, as mentioned, fix your schema design.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AJAX and it to run in every second or you can use 
meta tag : refresh

this will refresh page with php table